# How to use my own custom RecyclerView with overridden methods?

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, extends

I've currently created this basic RecyclerView from extending:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import androidx.annotation.Nullable
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class CustomRecyclerView : RecyclerView {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    override fun getBottomFadingEdgeStrength(): Float {
        return 0.0f
    }
}
```

In my XML I do:

```
    <com.rchan.android.ui.CustomRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/key_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false" />
```

In my fragment I do:

```
    key_list.apply {
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        keyListAdapter = KeyListAdapter(keyListViewActions)
        adapter = keyListAdapter
    }
```

Everything loads fine but for some reason the overridden methods I had to disable the bottom fading edge strength is not working? I try to debug point it but doesnt go in either.

Is there anyone who can bestow upon me some sage knowledge on how to get this working?

Thank You

Comment: RecyclerView does not even use fading edge by default. Perhaps you were trying to remove overscroll glow?

Comment: Im hoping to remove the grey blob that occurs when you scroll and reach end of list